# What difference does putting a 'forward slash' at the end, make to a url?

Tags: java, url, jakarta-ee, servlets, url-pattern

What is the difference between the 2 URL's :

```
http://localhost:8084/D_Nappster/NewServlet/
```

and

```
http://localhost:8084/D_Nappster/NewServlet
```

The first URL gets me a `404` response,while the second one works as expected.

From *web.xml* :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NewServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/NewServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Because there is no URL mapping for NewServlet/ in your web.xml. Your server dosent know where to redirect where a request that ends with NewServlet/ is received.

Comment: you might want to take a look at http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html

Answer (score 2):

In general, the first url will be treated as a directory, while the second will be treated as a file.

In your case you have no mapping for the first url so it's being treated as a directory which does not exist, causing a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a `/` at the end makes the server assume that it is a Folder and not a servlet mentioned in url-pattern.

```
http://localhost:8084/D_Nappster/NewServlet/
```

Therefore, in above case, it tries to find the default page for NewServlet Folder. Whereas, in second url, the server rightly concludes that it is a Servlet and renders UI perfelctly.

Also, you web.xml does not contain a definition for `NewServlet/` url-pattern and hence the 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

The first URL without the / goes and accesses the NewServlet class..

The second URL with the / tries to find a folder called NewServlet and access the default setting within the folder